# How can I ensure synchronous DDL operations on a table that is being replaced?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have multiple processes which are continually refreshing data in Redshift.  They start a transaction, create a new table, `COPY` all the data from S3 into the new table, then drop the old table and rename the new table to the old table.

pseudocode:

```
start transaction;
create table foo_temp;
copy into foo_temp from S3;
drop table foo;
rename table foo_temp to foo;
commit;
```

I have several dozen tables that I update in this way.  This works well but I would like to have multiple processes performing these table updates for redundancy purposes and to ensure that data is fairly fresh (different processes can update the data for different tables concurrently).

It works fine unless one process attempts to refresh a table that another process is working on.  In that case the second process gets blocked by the first until it commits, and when it commits the second process gets the error:

> ERROR:  table 12345 dropped by concurrent transaction

**Is there a simple way for me to guarantee that only one of my processes is refreshing a table so that the second process doesn't get into this situation?**

I considered creating a special lock table for each of my real tables.  The process would `LOCK` the special lock table before working on the companion real table.  I think that will work but I would like to avoid creating a special lock table for each of my tables.

Comment: Have you considered [Advisory Locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS)?

Comment: unfortunately that is one of the things Redshift does not support: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html

Comment: start with RENAME and allow reader to query it until the process is done

Answer (score 10):

you need to protect readers from seeing the drop, do this by:

- begin transaction
- rename main table to old_main_table
- rename tmp table to main table
- commit
- drop table old_main_table

```
 
    Conn #1         Conn #2
    --------------  ------------------------------------------
                    > create table bar (id int,id2 int,id3 int);
                    CREATE TABLE
    > begin;
    BEGIN
                    > begin;
                    BEGIN
                    > alter table bar rename to bar2;
                    ALTER TABLE
    > select * from bar;  
                    > create table bar (id int,id2 int,id3 int,id4 int);
                    CREATE TABLE
                    > commit; drop table bar2;
                    COMMIT
    id | id2 | id3 
    ----+-----+-----
    (0 rows)
    > commit;
    COMMIT
                    DROP TABLE
```

Comment: Since only the current session will reach the target_old table. It's very interesting to know why it matters, if the drop table command is after or before the commit command?

Comment: @AvivNoy the answer relates to this line in the [Redshift docs on Isolation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_serial_isolation.html):

"System catalog tables (PG) and other Amazon Redshift system tables (STL and STV) are not locked in a transaction; therefore, changes to database objects that arise from DDL and TRUNCATE operations are visible on commit to any concurrent transactions."

The rename and drop are, AFAICT, *not* part of the transaction, and immediately visible. DROP after COMMIT *ensures* no other connection has an outstanding reference to the table.