# Why is an implicit table lock being released prior to end of transaction in RedShift?

Tags: sql, etl, amazon-redshift

I have an ETL process that is building dimension tables incrementally in RedShift.  It performs actions in the following order:

1. Begins transaction
2. Creates a table staging_foo like foo
3. Copies data from external source into staging_foo
4. Performs mass insert/update/delete on foo so that it matches staging_foo
5. Drop staging_foo
6. Commit transaction

Individually this process works, but in order to achieve continuous streaming refreshes to `foo` and redundancy in the event of failure, I have several instances of the process running at the same time.  And when that happens I occasionally get concurrent serialization errors.  This is because both processes are replaying some of the same changes to `foo` from `foo_staging` in overlapping transactions.

What happens is that the first process creates the `staging_foo` table, and the second process is blocked when it attempts to create a table with the same name (this is what I want).  When the first process commits its transaction (which can take several seconds) I find that the second process gets unblocked before the commit is complete.  So it appears to be getting a snapshot of the `foo` table before the commit is in place, which causes the inserts/updates/deletes (some of which may be redundant) to fail.

I am theorizing based on the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_serial_isolation.html where it says:

> Concurrent transactions are invisible to each other; they cannot detect each other's changes. Each concurrent transaction will create a snapshot of the database at the beginning of the transaction. A database snapshot is created within a transaction on the first occurrence of most SELECT statements, DML commands such as COPY, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE, and TRUNCATE, and the following DDL commands :
>
> ALTER TABLE (to add or drop columns)
>
> CREATE TABLE
>
> DROP TABLE
>
> TRUNCATE TABLE

The documentation quoted above is somewhat confusing to me because it first says a snapshot will be created at the beginning of a transaction, but subsequently says a snapshot will be created only at the first occurrence of some specific DML/DDL operations.

I do not want to do a deep copy where I replace `foo` instead of incrementally updating it.  I have other processes that continually query this table so there is never a time when I can replace it without interruption.  Another question asks a similar question for deep copy but it will not work for me: [How can I ensure synchronous DDL operations on a table that is being replaced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692518/how-can-i-ensure-synchronous-ddl-operations-on-a-table-that-is-being-replaced)

Is there a way for me to perform my operations in a way that I can avoid concurrent serialization errors?  I need to ensure that read access is available for `foo` so I can't `LOCK` that table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, Postgres (and therefore Redshift [more or less]) uses [MVCC (Multi Version Concurrency Control)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) for transaction isolation instead of a [db/table/row/page locking model (as seen in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189849%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), MySQL, etc.). Simplistically every transaction operates on the data **as it existed when the transaction started**.

So your comment "I have several instances of the process running at the same time" explains the problem. If Process 2 starts while Process 1 is running then Process 2 has no visibility of the results from Process 1.